# Responsive view for position:absolute

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position, responsive

I am having a background image on top of that need to place sub images which will look like connection to a circuit.

**Current Result:**

```css
.container {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfygH.png');
    height: 400px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: stretch;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.coil {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
    left: 10%;   
}
.evaporator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 55%;
}
.compressor {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
    left: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="coil">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKUms.png" alt="coil-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="evaporator">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/spv58.png" alt="evaporator-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="compressor">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzSaH.png" alt="compressor-image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the images position absolute with class name `coil`, `evaporator`, `compressor` responsive on all the screens for tablet view?

But for now the absolute positioned elements get's distorted when I switch to different view using developer tool.

This app is not for mobile but only supports tablet view with pixels starting from `1024px`.

**Expected Result:**

[image]

**Update with pixels:**

After the solution from Quentin, I have updated the code with pixels for `.container` and absolute elements with `top` and `left` as pixels.

```css
.container {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfygH.png');
    height: 400px;
    width: 750px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: stretch;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.coil {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 200px;   
}
.evaporator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 415px;
}
.compressor {
    position: absolute;
    top: 220px;
    left: 440px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="coil">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKUms.png" alt="coil-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="evaporator">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/spv58.png" alt="evaporator-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="compressor">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzSaH.png" alt="compressor-image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

But issue here is that for fixed width of `.container` like `750px` it works (That is how i have given the value).

-> Consider that for `1024px` sized screen, then `.container` will be `750px` width.

-> But if screen size exceeds for eg `1248px`, then `.container` will be like `800px` width.

As the width of `.container` changes, the absolute positioned elements still stays in the same place as older.

So in this case I need to give around `75%` of the screen size to this container. At right section, there will be another div placed. Kindly help me to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say your viewport width won't be below 1024px (i.e. not less than the background image), I would fix the width and height for the background element, remove the `background-size`setting (making it the original image size) and adjust its `background-position` to `top left` (which is the default, BTW, since all the percentages of the other div positions also are measured from top and left.

In addition, you need to apply `position: relative` to the container div to make it the parent (and therefore the size reference) for the other divs containing the images.

Finally, you need to adjust the top and left positions of the other divs (see below).

This is not really responsive, but since your viewport won't get smaller than the container, it actually doesn't have to be, except if you would want the images to grow (but which would result in rather bad image quality)

```css
.container {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfygH.png');
    height: 401px;
    width: 688px;
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}
.coil {
    position: absolute;
    top: 49.55%;
    left: 24.3%;   
}
.evaporator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7.25%;
    left: 54.5%;
}
.compressor {
    position: absolute;
    top: 53.15%;
    left: 59.2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="coil">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKUms.png" alt="coil-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="evaporator">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/spv58.png" alt="evaporator-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="compressor">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzSaH.png" alt="compressor-image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Addition: If you absolutely need it to grow with viewport size, you can add a media query and inside that use `transform: scale()` on the container and add `transform-origin: top center;`. In addition you can center the container by adding `margin: 0 auto;`:

```css
.container {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfygH.png');
    height: 401px;
    width: 688px;
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.coil {
    position: absolute;
    top: 49.55%;
    left: 24.3%;   
}
.evaporator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7.25%;
    left: 54.5%;
}
.compressor {
    position: absolute;
    top: 53.15%;
    left: 59.2%;
}
@media (min-width: 1300px) {
  .container {
    transform: scale(2.0);
    transform-origin: top center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="coil">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKUms.png" alt="coil-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="evaporator">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/spv58.png" alt="evaporator-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="compressor">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzSaH.png" alt="compressor-image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Johannes, Thanks for your detailed answer and could you also help me with the scenario I have mentioned at last updated question. Consider that the `.container` has `width: 688px` for `1024px`, but if I view in little more bigger tablet with `1428px`, then I need to increase the width of the `.container` as well like `75%` of the total width of the screen is allocated to this `.container` div. In this case if I increase the width of `.container` div then I also need to change the pixels for `position: absolute` elements. Is there a better way to handle this scenario?

Comment: @HelloWorld Hi, I was still busy editing the second part of my answer while you already wrote your comment - please have a look at it again and keep in mind that there could be more than one media query with other `scale` values.

Comment: Thanks for your help bro. I accepted your answer as it completely solves what I asked in question. But one request if you can help, I am actually implementing this in a react-native application and there is a component to include `backgroundImage` https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground for this which don't have the property `background-position`. If you see any option of how can we implement this in `react-native`, then please post that here in the comment bro. And more thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: @HelloWorld i am sorry, but I don't have any experience in react...

Comment: Okay let me check for it. Thanks again bro.

Answer (score 0):

Your image sizes are based on the intrinsic dimensions of the images — which are pixels.

Your positioning is based on *percentages* of the containing block, which (given `.container` isn't positioned) will probably be the *window size*.

As the window size changes, the relative positions of the parts of the image will change but the sizes of the images will now.

**You need to be consistent**.

Either:

- Define all your lengths in pixels *or*
- Define all your lengths (including the image sizes which you aren't defining at all at present) as percentages of the same thing

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, Could you kindly give some working example as snippet for my better understanding. Also is there a better solution of handling it like using `flexbox` or this `position:absolute` is the right approach? Any good suggestion with working example would help me a lot and to understand better as i am struggling with it for long duration.

Comment: I have updated the question with pixels and provided the issues I face when the pixel of the screen changes. Kindly help me. I can provide more inputs if needed.